# Linear independence of Spacetime coordinates

Tags: special-relativity

So I have seen the identity  $$ \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\nu } = \delta^\mu_\nu. $$

The definition of four-velocity is:

$$ U^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau} = \frac{dt}{d \tau}\frac{dx^\mu}{dt}. $$

By the above identity I find

$$ U^\mu =  \gamma \delta^\mu_0. $$

i.e. only the time component is non-zero. This contradicts the standard four-velocity as being

$$ \mathbf{U} = \gamma(1,v_x,v_y,v_z)$$

This standard form for the four-velocity implies that $$ \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^0} \neq 0.$$

Where am I going wrong? Are the space-time coordinates really linearly independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up two types of derivatives.

- The partial derivative $\partial x^\mu / \partial t$ represents how $x^\mu$ changes as $t$ changes, holding all else constant.
- The total derivative $dx^\mu / dt$ represents the rate of change of $x^\mu$ along a trajectory $x^\mu(t)$.

For example, you can use the chain rule to compute the total derivative in terms of the partial derivatives of the trajectory.

Basically, the spacetime coordinates are independent, but not if you constrain yourself to lie on a trajectory.